# how to call post method from vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-touchkit, vaadin6

how to call dopost method from vaadin application?
BrowserWindowOpener component always call doGet() of servlet. I want to call dopost method so that parameter is not shown at the browser addressbar if I redirect to another url. Will it be ok to use Form Sender add-on??.. If it is ok, then How to use it?... Please reply soon...

Comment: i would guess, that you have to do some ajax call on the target site then, as the window opened there is just a browser window with the url opened.  or pass the params via GET in the url.

Comment: Show me your code, on what you are doing and Why do you want to redirect? Are you submitting the data to third party websites? If you can give additional details I can help you